# Check all validations with jquery before posting in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to post my MVC form with jquery . My view model is this

```
 public class DemoViewModel
  {
    [Required]
    public string  FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]

    public string LastName { get; set; }
  }
```

and my controller is

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult LongRunningDemoProcess(DemoViewModel model)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return Json(model, "json");
    }
```

and my view has the following code

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.DemoViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}



@using (Html.BeginForm("LongRunningDemoProcess", "Home", FormMethod.Post,
new { encType = "multipart/form-data", id = "myform", name = "myform" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName,
        new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName,
        new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="operation" id="process" value="process" />
}

<div id="divProcessing">
    <p>Processing, please wait . . . <img src="../../Content/ajax-loader.gif"></p>
</div>

<div id="divResult">

</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Hide the "busy" Gif at load:
            $("#divProcessing").hide();

            // Handle the form submit event, and make the Ajax request:
            $("#myform").on("submit", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                 // Show the "busy" Gif:
                $("#divProcessing").show();
                var url = $(this).attr("action");
                var formData = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (resp) {
                        // Hide the "busy" gif:
                        $("#divProcessing").hide();

                        // Do something useful with the data:
                        $("<h3>" + resp.FirstName + " " + resp.LastName + "</h3>").appendTo("#divResult");
                    }
                })
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

but the problem is that even if their are errors of required field the form is posted and get the result

[image]

I tried to test this code `if($("#myform").valid())` but there is no method available .
How can I test the validation by using jquery.validate.js as it is included already.
Thanks

Comment: Have you included jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js?

Comment: No only validate.js  in bundles                                                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

Comment: Then there should be no problem using `.valid()` (and therefore preventing the ajax post). What was the code you were using?

Comment: I have posted all the codes above should I have to include  jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js?

Comment: you need to call it as  $("#myform").validate()

Answer (score 8):

Due to submitting the form via ajax you will have to manually call it.

This is one approach you could take:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
        $form.validate();
        if ($form.valid()) {
            // ajax call
        }
        else {
          // Failed show errors
        }
```

If it fails the errors are contained within `$form.validate().errorList` but you have to manually parse them.

You can do this as follows:

```
    $.each($form.validate().errorList, function (key, value) {
        $errorSpan = $("span[data-valmsg-for='" + value.element.id + "']");
        $errorSpan.html("<span style='color:red'>" + value.message + "</span>");
        $errorSpan.show();
    });
```

This simply replaces your validation for messages manually.

Answer (score 6):

I have solved it by including jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js in my bundles

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"
                    ));
```

and check like this

```
  if (!$("#myform").valid()) {

           alert('not valid');

                   }
else{
// ajax logic
    }
```

Comment: Adding reference to ~/bundles/jqueryval without unobstructive js did it for me,thanks anyways